# How to seperate BlueStore from ceph and run it solely?

Tags: ceph, object-storage, cephfs

I am learning BlueStore. I want to run it so that I could get a concrete workflow. However, BlueStore is integrated into CEPH which makes it difficult for me to focus only on what I interest.

So how could I separate BlueStore from CEPH and run it solely?